# I have an internal class of KeyListener that is returning an error saying "is not abstract and does not override abstract method"

Tags: java, keylistener

I have a JPanel that contains around 10 JTextFields, I want to be able to set focus on a particular textfield once up or down arrow is clicked on the keyboard. So, if a text field in the middle is focused and up arrow is clicked the focus will go to the text field above it and likewise if the down arrow is clicked it will focus on the text field below it. I created an internal class of Key Listener patterned like my ActionListener class which I assume I can do. There just seems to be an error when I compile it saying

`panelEncodeMain.HandleKeyListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method keyReleased(KeyEvent) in KeyListener`.

Can anyone help me solve the problems? Thanks in advance.

```
public panelEncodemain()
{
    //setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    HandleControlButton control = new HandleControlButton();
    HandleKeyListener keycontrol = new HandleKeyListener();

    btn_testing = new JButton("Test Focus");
    btn_testing.addActionListener(control);

    lbl_page = new JLabel("Page :");
    lbl_line = new JLabel("Line :");
    lbl_refpage = new JLabel("Ref. Page :");
    lbl_refline = new JLabel("Ref. Line :");
    lbl_transdate = new JLabel("Transaction Date :");
    lbl_desc = new JLabel("Description :");
    lbl_accountcode = new JLabel("Account Code :");
    lbl_codetype = new JLabel("Code Type :");
    lbl_issuedate = new JLabel("Issue Date :");
    lbl_amount = new JLabel("Amount :");

    lbl_page.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lbl_line.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lbl_refpage.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lbl_refline.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lbl_transdate.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lbl_desc.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lbl_accountcode.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lbl_codetype.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lbl_issuedate.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    lbl_amount.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));

    text_page = new JTextField(7);
    text_line = new JTextField(5);
    text_refpage = new JTextField(40);
    text_refline = new JTextField(40);
    text_transdate = new JTextField(10);
    text_desc = new JTextField(40);
    text_desc.addKeyListener(keycontrol);
    text_accountcode = new JTextField(5);
    text_codetype = new JTextField(5);
    text_issuedate = new JTextField(10);
    text_amount = new JTextField(20);


    text_page.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    text_line.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    text_refpage.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    text_refline.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    text_transdate.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    text_desc.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    text_accountcode.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    text_codetype.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    text_issuedate.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    text_amount.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));


    //text_desc.setEditable(false);

    //first row

    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 0;
    c.insets = new Insets(5,0,0,10);
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    add(lbl_page, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(text_page, c);

    //second row

    c.gridy++;

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    c.gridx=0;
    add(lbl_line, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(text_line, c);

    //third row

    c.gridy++;

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    c.gridx=0;
    add(lbl_refpage, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(text_refpage, c);

    //fourth row

    c.gridy++;

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    c.gridx=0;
    add(lbl_refline, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(text_refline, c);

    //fifth row

    c.gridy++;

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    c.gridx=0;
    add(lbl_transdate, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(text_transdate, c);

    //sixth row

    c.gridy++;

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    c.gridx=0;
    add(lbl_desc, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(text_desc, c);

    //seventh row

    c.gridy++;

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    c.gridx=0;
    add(lbl_accountcode, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(text_accountcode, c);

    //eighth row

    c.gridy++;

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    c.gridx=0;
    add(lbl_codetype, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(text_codetype, c);

    //ninth row

    c.gridy++;

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    c.gridx=0;
    add(lbl_issuedate, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(text_issuedate, c);

    //tenth row

    c.gridy++;

    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    c.gridx=0;
    add(lbl_amount, c);

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
    add(text_amount, c);

    //tenth row

    c.gridy++;

    c.gridx = 1;
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
    add(btn_testing, c);

}

class HandleControlButton implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();

        if(source == btn_testing)
        {
                text_desc.requestFocus();    
        }
    }
}

class HandleKeyListener implements KeyListener
{
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent x)
    {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
}
```

I expect to be able to shift focus from one text field to the next using up or down buttons on the keyboard.

Comment: so implement the method you didn't implement. If you implement an interface, and your class isn't abstract, it means you have to provide an implementation of that interfaces methods

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned in the comments the error means that you have to implement all the methods from the interface KeyListener. It has three methods

- keyTyped (that you already implemented)
- keyPressed (not implemented)
- KeyReleased (not implemented)

So you could add an empty implementation for these methods but in this case the easiest way would be to extend the class [KeyAdapter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyAdapter.html) instead of implementing KeyListener (because KeyAdapter implements KeyListener and has only empty methods implemented which is exactly what you need here)

So you can change the KeyListener class to this:

```
class HandleKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent x) {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Then it should work.

Comment: Thanks I typed in the missing methods and it worked.. maybe I'll try KeyAdapter..